# Getting keys of a class in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, methods

I have a class with a lot of methods let's call it myClass. I'm calling it like this:

```
myClass[key]()
```

Is there a way to get the possible values from key? I hoped for something like keyof myClass, but I got 'myClass refers to a value, but is being used as a type here'

The problem is probably that as of now myClass is defined in a .js-file and encapsulated like this:

```
const myClass = new MyActualClass();
export default myClass
```

Is it possible to extract the information without converting the .js file to typescript, and extract the information from MyActualClass directly?

Comment: Maybe `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myClass.prototype)`?

Comment: Mh, TJ is right. Please see how to make a [mcve].

Comment: sorry all of you. I've updated the description now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the *runtime property names*, you can use `Object.keys` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

At the TypeScript level, if you wanted to declare a variable that could contain the keys for an instance of your class, you'd do it like this:

```
let s: keyof typeof myClass;
```

[Example on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vWAewDsIAXAJwFdhi9SAKLHRgB3ICMQBLYaAMzzwBc0EqQ4EA5gBoGjbC3ZdorMKSEix4mdACUWzIwC+GIxhABTYtDzQAvNAJmA7nCQoItAERgPk6B9Ye2gDcGKYWwkIA1mbweDzQxPBMZnFWQUA)

Comment: Thanks! I always fail when I have to combine several keywords in typescript.