# Matching parameters in signature

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to tell typescript that method 'foo' always comes with FooData, etc for this code:

```
const search = (data: FooData|BarData|BazData, method:"foo"|"bar"|"baz") => {
  //Do some common stuff
  return myClass[method](data);
}
```

the myClass Methods has signature like this:

```
foo(data: FooData) => {
  //Do Something
}
```

Edit: Possible relevant: [Getting keys of a class in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130794/getting-keys-of-a-class-in-typescript)

Comment: Create 3 function overloads https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use overloads, but if you have a class and want to keep the function parameters in sync with the class you could use some conditional types to extract those specific methods and the type of the parameter and use a generic type argument to the function to let the compiler know about the relation between the `method` and `data` parameter:

```
type BarData = { bar: number }
type FooData = { foo: number }
type BazData = { baz: number }

class MyClass {

    foo(data: FooData) {
        //Do Something
    }
    bar(data: BarData) {
        //Do Something
    }

    baz(data: BazData) {
        //Do Something
    }    
}
type KeyOfType<T, V> = {
    [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends V? P: never
}[keyof T]

type Data<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends Record<K, (data: infer D) => void> ? D : never;

const search = <K extends KeyOfType<MyClass, (a: any) => any>>(method: K, data: Data<MyClass, K>) => {
    //Do some common stuff
    let myClass = new MyClass();
    return myClass[method](data);
}

search("foo", { foo: 1 })
search("foo", { bar: 1}) // err
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#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)

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Would it be possible to change KeyOfType so it works on myClass (rather then MyClass)?

Comment: @MrMamen You mean on a variable instead of the class? Probably, depends where it is defined, using `typeof myClass` instead of `MyClass` might work, but you have to show me more of your code to say for sure..

Comment: Yes `typeof myClass` seems to do the same thing. If you want to limit the allows methods you could expand KeyOfType to: `[P in keyof T]: P extends Methods ? T[P] extends V? P: never : never` where Methods could be `'foo'|'bar'`

Comment: You can just use the union instead of KeyOfType. If you already known the keys you want. KeyOfType is there to extract the keys without having to type them

Comment: quite right. I assumed `T[P] extends V`was important, but every constraint seems to be within Data.